# WordPress redirect loses parameters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

The issue:

I'm using (what I think is) a fairly standard multisite WordPress setup, which is using qTranslate for internationalisation. I have a menu that generates links of the form:

```
http://www.example.com/theblog/thepage/?lang=XX
```

However, going there returns a `302`, and redirects to

```
http://www.example.com/theblog/thepage
```

without the slash *and without the query parameters* (thus switching the language to default).

I am not very good with `mod_rewrite` nor WordPress, so I would appreciate if someone could help me debug exactly what is happening. My hypothesis is there is a rogue redirect going on to remove the slash; but I can't see any rule in `.htaccess` that would account for it - unless WordPress itself was doing it, for some reason. Here is what rewrite log says (edited for brevity and anonymity):

```
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) [perdir /...] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/wordpress/theblog' pattern='-f' => not-matched
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) [perdir /...] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/wordpress/theblog' pattern='-d' => not-matched
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add path info postfix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog -> /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/theblog/thepage -> theblog/thepage
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '.' to uri 'theblog/thepage'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (2) [perdir /...] rewrite 'theblog/thepage' -> 'index.php'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/wordpress/index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (2) [perdir /...] trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /
...[rid#...a0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.php -> index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (1) [perdir /...] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
...[rid#...68/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.php -> index.php
...[rid#...68/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'index.php'
...[rid#...68/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /...] pass through /var/www/wordpress/index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) [perdir /...] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico' pattern='-f' => not-matched
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) [perdir /...] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico' pattern='-d' => not-matched
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '.' to uri 'favicon.ico'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (2) [perdir /...] rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> 'index.php'
...[rid#...a0/initial] (3) [perdir /...] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/www/wordpress/index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (2) [perdir /...] trying to replace prefix /var/www/wordpress/ with /
...[rid#...a0/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.php -> index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
...[rid#...a0/initial] (1) [perdir /...] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
...[rid#...28/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /...] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/wordpress/index.php -> index.php
...[rid#...28/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /...] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'index.php'
...[rid#...28/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /...] pass through /var/www/wordpress/index.php
```

I'd be grateful if someone could puzzle out why this happens, what makes it happen, and how I can stop it from happening.

**EDIT** `.htaccess` is, I believe, standard for WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: And the `.htaccess` rule being used is?

Comment: @Prix: I added the `.htaccess` file contents. I have no clue which rule is being used, which is why I'm asking here. I am not even 100% sure if it's something `mod_rewrite` does or something Wordpress is doing.

Comment: Have you tried turning on qTranslate friendly SEO? As it is, there is nothing here that would replace the query string except for the wp-admin portion maybe.

Comment: @Amadan What was the answer, I am also having the same issue here ?